# Unable to implement django-rules authorization

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework, authorization, django-authentication

I'm a new django user looking for some help with **django-rules**. I'm trying to set up an authorization system that is **'OR'** based. I have a 'File' model. I would like only the creator to be able to delete it, but a specific set of users to edit it. I've been able to followed their tutorial and implementation throughout; it works in the shell but not on my site. At the moment no one can delete or update anything.

My view currently looks like:

```
class FileUpdateView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generics.RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    """
    View updating details of a bill
    """
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_required = 'fileupload.change_file'
    raise_exception = True

class FileDeleteView(PermissionRequiredMixin, generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    """
    View for deleting a bill
    """
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
    permission_required = 'fileupload.delete_file'
    raise_exception = True
```

The rules themselves are:

```
import rules

@rules.predicate
def is_creator(user, file):
    """Checks if user is file's creator"""
    return file.owner == user

is_editor = rules.is_group_member('ReadAndWrite')

rules.add_perm('fileupload.change_file', is_editor | is_creator)
rules.add_perm('fileupload.delete_file', is_creator)
```

I know I'm close I feel like I'm just missing one step.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

please check & add settings file authentication backend for Django-rules. Also, you are mixing Django rest permissions with Django-rules permission. you need to check Django-rules permission in Django-rest permissions on view.

in short.

define a custom permission in rest-framework like this.

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class RulesPermissions(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.has_perm('books.edit_book', obj)
```

in viewset.

```
class BookView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (RulesPermissions,)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working with the django REST framework and django-rules for a project and found an answer to your question.

The django REST framework uses an API view which is not compatible with rules' `views.PermissionRequiredMixin`, the authorization workflow and methods called during the API dispatch is different from django's class based view.

Try the following mixin for django REST framework API views and their subclasses:

```
import six
from django.core.exceptions import ImproperlyConfigured


class PermissionRequiredMixin:

    permission_required = None

    def get_permission_object(self):
        object_getter = getattr(self, 'get_object', lambda: None)
        return object_getter()

    def get_permission_required(self):

        if self.permission_required is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                '{0} is missing the permission_required attribute. Define '
                '{0}.permission_required, or override '
                '{0}.get_permission_required().'
                .format(self.__class__.__name__)
            )

        if isinstance(self.permission_required, six.string_types):
            perms = (self.permission_required, )
        else:
            perms = self.permission_required

        return perms

    def check_permissions(self, request):
        obj = self.get_permission_object()
        user = request.user
        missing_permissions = [perm for perm in self.get_permission_required()
                               if not user.has_perm(perm, obj)]
        if any(missing_permissions):
            self.permission_denied(
                request,
message=('MISSING: {}'.format(', '.join(missing_permissions))))
```

With this mixin you're not forced to write a REST framework permission for each rules permission.